# Can anyone issue a bill regarding damage identified in your former appartment?

Tags: rent, france

I left my old appartement 2 months ago, I just received the regulation regarding the charges, rent, repairs and security deposit. As the title mention it, there were some costs due to cleaning of floors, sink and stuff like that for 95€. So be it. I don't know why but I wanted to check who issued the bill.

I looked up the registration number (SIRET) and found that his line of work was "Organisation de foires, salons professionnels et congrès" which you could roughly translate to the organisation of trade fairs, professional exhibitions and congresses. On paper it doesn't really seem like someone with the expertise to issue a bill for repairs in an appartment but I'm no expert in the law department either.

So I'm wondering if anyone who has the ability to issue bills can issue one regarding the matter at hands, appartment repairs.

For the information I live in France and I did my research but couldn't find anything regarding any legislation imposing some kind of craftsman to estimate the repairs.

Comment: Presumably this tradesman was hired by your landlord, who is the one you actually have to pay?

Comment: @TimLymington didn't really pay anyone, I made a deposit when I entered the place which they gave you back if everything is ok when you leave. So they gave me my deposit back minus the money to cover for the repair.

Comment: Whether or not financing the repairs came directly from your wallet or through the previously submitted security deposit doesn't really matter. The point @TimLymington was making was that SIRET is probably the entity hired to perform those tasks.